# I can't get grep to find "configname:.*:" from a file

Tags: grep, wildcard

I am trying to get strings that are separated by colons from a file with grep. I have managed fine so far but I ran into a problem where grep is just ignoring one of the characters I am trying to include in the search.

The file I am searching contains this line
`configname:user:ip:password:macaddr`

and the command I am running is `grep -o "configname:.*:" sshutil_config`

I thought this would find "configname:user:" but all it does is remove "macaddr" from the output. `configname:user:ip:password:`

The username will change and so I never know what it is so I can't grep specifically for it but I will know the configname and so I am trying to search for the username using it. I need to get the username out of the file as input and save it to a variable using `usr=$(grep -o "whatever_this_needs_to_be" sshutil_config)`

Thanks in advance,
-A\\/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also possible if you don't want to use grep

> user="$( cut -d ':' -f 2 <<< "$data" )"

Comment: won't that grab only 2nd field; he wants first 2?

Comment: You are right. I thought he only needs the user there.

Comment: After I posted my question I was thinking about a different way I could accomplish my overall goal which is getting all the strings that are separated by colons, out of the file and saved as separate variables. I found I can do this with $IFS and read in bash.

Comment: If you need all of them in an array, IFS is also the way for it.

Comment: yup, sometimes it's better to avoid regex altogether if you can--it can be error prone and/or computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1):

Change `"configname:.*:"` to `"configname:[^:]*:"`

Comment: can you use code fences please? your comment got styled instead of just being written.